# "Exclude from StyleCop" and "Include in StyleCop" missing

Tags: visual-studio-2017, stylecop

I have StyleCop 4.7.55.0 installed. On the context (right-click) menu in VS2017 Professional when editing a C# file, the option `Run StyleCop` is present, but neither `Exclude from StyleCop` nor `Include In StyleCop` is shown. Checking `Tools`>`Customise` `[Commands]` for the context menu `Project and Solution Context Menus|Item` shows all 3 menu items.

What should I check to see why they are not enabled?